# Weird characters in email

Tags: c#, email, mime

I have written a mail-processing program, which basically slaps a template on incoming mail and forwards it on.  Incoming mail goes to a Gmail account, which I download using POP, then I read the mail (both html and plain text multipart-MIME), make whatever changes I need to the template, then create a new mail with the appropriate plain+html text and send it on to another address.

Trouble is, when the mail gets to the other side, some of the mails have been mangled, with weird characters like `Ã` and `Â` magically getting inserted.  They weren't in the original mails, they're not in my template, and I can't find any sort of predictable pattern as to when these characters appear. I'm sure it's got something to do with the encoding properties of the mails, but I am making sure to set both the charset and the transfer encoding of the outgoing mail to be the same as the incoming mail.  So what else do I need to do?

**EDIT:** Here's a snipped sample of an incoming mail:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=0A=0ASafari Special:=0A=0A=A0=0A=0ASafari in Thornybush Priv=
ate Game Reserve 9-12=0AJanuary 2012 (3nights)
```

After processing, this comes out as:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=0D=0A=0D=0ASafari Special:=0D=0A=0D=0A=C2=A0=0D=0A=0D=0A=
Safari in Thornybush Private Game Reserve 9-12=0D=0AJanuary=
2012 (3nights)
```

Notice the insertion of the `=0D` and `=C2` characters (aside from a few `=0A`'s that weren't in the original).

So what does you think is happening here?

**ANOTHER CLUE:** Here's my code that creates the alternate view:

```
var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, "text/html");
htmlView.ContentType.CharSet = charSet;
htmlView.TransferEncoding = transferEncoding;
m.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Along the lines of what @mjwills suggested, perhaps the `CreateAlternativeViewFromString()` method already assumes UTF-8, and changing it later to iso-8859-1 doesn't make a difference?

Comment: This sounds like an encoding issue. Post an example of a message that you send and the resulting garbled message. You should have a look at the binary form of the mail at each stage in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So every =0A is becoming =0D=0A.
And every =A0 is becoming =C2=A0.

The former looks like it might be related to [Carriage Return / Line Feeds](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=68687).
The latter looks like it might be related to [What is "=C2=A0" in MIME encoded, quoted-printable text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774471/what-is-c2-a0-in-mime-encoded-quoted-printable-text/2774507#2774507).

My guess is that even though you have specified the charset, something alone the line is treating it as UTF8.

You may want to try using [this form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144595.aspx) of CreateAlternateViewFromString, where the ContentType.CharSet is set appropriately.

Comment: The other signature of CreateAlternateViewFromString makes it even worse.  Instead of mangling the text, now the whole multipart-MIME structure gets messed up, such that the entire email appears as an attachment!

Comment: Yep, the other overload of CreateAlternateViewFromString did the trick.  Thanks!