# How to remove C2 A0 in QByteArray before converting to QString?

Tags: qstring, qbytearray

I have a QByteArray that has "C2 A0" in it that when converted to a QString makes "=C2=A0". I remove this "=C2=A0" and replace it with a space before I send it to be converted to a PDF. Problem is I always get the Â in the resultant PDF. I have tried all kinds way to try and fix this. The file I send the pdf conversion service is verified not to have the "=C2=A0" in it yet it still appears. I need to remove this "C2 A0" from the QByteArray before converting to a QString. Is there a function where I can remove those bytes before the conversion to QString? I opened the file in a Mac hex editor and even with the "=C2=A0" removed the "C2 A0" is still there. I need to remove this bytes for proper conversion.

This answer isn't helping me: [What is "=C2=A0" in MIME encoded, quoted-printable text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774471/what-is-c2-a0-in-mime-encoded-quoted-printable-text)

Comment: Have you considered using one of [toLocal8Bit()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit) and friends?  For more details: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#converting-between-8-bit-strings-and-unicode-strings

Comment: Convert the QString back to a different type of QByteArray? Is that what you are saying? Then pick the C2 A0 from it somehow and then convert back to a QString again? Can't I remove the C2 A0 before I convert to a QString so I can do that once?