# Apache POI Anomalous Whitespace (Resolved: \u00A0 non-breaking space)

Tags: java, apache-poi

EDIT: Resolved Answer:  Was a 00a0 nonbreaking space, not a c0a0 nonbreaking space.

After using Apache POI to convert from docx to plaintext, and then reading the plaintext into Java and trying to parse it I've run into the following problems.

Output:

```
" "
first characterequals SPACE OR TAB 
false
[B@5e481248
[B@66d3c617
ARRAYTOSTRING SPACE: [32]
ARRAYTOSTRING ?????: [-62, -96]
```

For code:

```
System.out.println("\t\"" + line.substring(0,1) + "\"\n\tfirst characterequals SPACE OR TAB \n\t" + (line.substring(0,1).equals(" ") 
                        || line.substring(0,1).equals("\t") ));
System.out.println(line.substring(0,1).getBytes());
System.out.println(" ".getBytes());
System.out.println("ARRAYTOSTRING SPACE: " + Arrays.toString(" ".getBytes()));
System.out.println("ARRAYTOSTRING ?????: " + Arrays.toString(line.substring(0,1).getBytes()));
```

String.trim() does not get rid of it
String.replaceAll("\s" , "") does not get rid of it

I'm trying to parse an enormous materials document and this is turning into a major hurdle.  I have no idea what's going on or how to interface with it, can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?

Comment: You really should add at least a snippet of your extraction code.

Comment: I'm not sure the extraction code would make much sense out of context, it's just pulling line by line and this debug snippet is duplicating the loop checks to make it visible what's actually being compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This translates to the bytes with hex codes `c2 a0`, which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774471/what-is-c2-a0-in-mime-encoded-quoted-printable-text) is a UTF-8 encoded non-breaking space. Note that this is *not* really a space and \s will not match it.

Comment: 1) Is there an easily referable source / set of characters that will appear as whitespace but not match it (or regex to include these)

2) Does this character have an escape sequence or anything simple that can be matched to it?

Comment: I used http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/space (though it contains a lot of other results). The escape sequence should be (somewhat unsurprisingly) `\u{c2a0}`.

Comment: Are there any other faux whitespace I might run into, or is this the outlier

Comment: Again, look at the amp-what page, it lists a few. Notable offfenders are \u200B, the zero-width whitespace as well as \u2002 up to \u200a (various white space widths) and \u200F (which is a narrow non-breaking space).

Comment: Actually, turns out that your evaluation is incorrect.

The toString of the byte string of \uc2a0 is [-20, -118, -96], and a base val.equals("\uc2a0") returns false.

Searching on the character from the output returns &#160, not familiar with unicode enough to know how that converts to hex such that you got c2a0 or how to escape it.

According to unicodelookup the hex is just a0.

Comment: #160 is a non-breaking space. The same analysis applies. See http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/%23160

Comment: The analysis applies, but it required further investigation to implement.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
 String valor = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.normalizeSpace(java.text.Normalizer.normalize(valor, java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD));
```