# PHP html_entity_decode and trim confusion

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `strip_tags` and `trim` to detect if a string contains empty html?

```
$description = '<p>&nbsp;</p>';

$output = trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

var_dump($output);
```

> string 'Â ' (length=2)

My debug to try figure this out:

```
$description = '<p>&nbsp;</p>';

$test = mb_detect_encoding($description);
$test .= "\n";
$test .= trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
$test .= "\n";
$test .= html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

file_put_contents('debug.txt', $test);
```

Output: debug.txt

```
ASCII
 
<p> </p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `var_dump(urlencode($output))` you'll see that it outputs `string(6) "%C2%A0"` hence the charcodes are 0xC2 and 0xA0. [These two charcodes are unicode for "non-breaking-space"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774507/247893). Make sure your file is saved in UTF-8 format and your HTTP headers are UTF-8 format.

That said, to trim this character you can use regex with the unicode modifier (instead of trim):

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/462170):

```
<?php

$description = '<p>&nbsp;</p>';

$output = trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

var_dump(urlencode($output)); // string(6) "%C2%A0"

// -------

$output = preg_replace('~^\s+|\s+$~', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

var_dump(urlencode($output)); // string(6) "%C2%A0"

// -------

$output = preg_replace('~^\s+|\s+$~u', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
// Unicode! -----------------------^

var_dump(urlencode($output)); // string(0) ""
```

**Regex autopsy**:

- `~` - the regex modifier delimiter - must be before the regex, and then before the modifiers
- `^\s+` - the start of the string immediately followed by one or more whitespaces (one or more whitespace characters in the start of the string) - *(`^` means start of the string, `\s` means a whitespace character, `+` means "matched 1 to infinity times")*
- `|` - OR
- `\s+$` - one or more whitespace characters immediately followed by the end of the string (one or more whitespace characters in the end of the string)
- `~` - the ending regex modifier delimiter
- `u` - the regex modifier - here using the [unicode modifier (`PCRE_UTF8`)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to make sure we replace unicode whitespace characters.

Comment: Autopsy is a fantastic word in this context.