# Fixing 'invalid reference format' error in docker-image-resource put

Tags: docker, concourse

Currently trying to build and push docker images, issue is that I'm receiving a this message from concourse during wordpress-release put step:

```
waiting for docker to come up...
invalid reference format
```

Here's the important bit of the Concourse Pipeline.

```
- name: wordpress-release
  type: docker-image
  source:
        repository: #############.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wordpress-release
        aws_access_key_id: #############
        aws_secret_access_key: #############
- name: mysql-release
  type: docker-image
  source:
        repository: #############.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mysql-release
        aws_access_key_id: #############
        aws_secret_access_key: #############
jobs:
- name: job-hello-world
  plan:
  - get: wordpress-website
  - task: write-release-tag
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: registry-image
        source: { repository: alpine/git }
      inputs:
        - name: wordpress-website
      outputs:
        - name: tags
      run:
        dir: wordpress-website
        path: sh
        args:
          - -exc
          - |
            printf $(basename $(git remote get-url origin) | sed 's/\.[^.]*$/-/')$(git tag --points-at HEAD) > ../tags/release-tag
  - put: wordpress-release
    params:
      build: ./wordpress-website/.
      dockerfile: wordpress-website/shared-wordpress-images/wordpress/wordpress-release/Dockerfile
      tag_file: tags/release-tag
  - put: mysql-release
    params:
      build: ./wordpress-website/
      dockerfile: wordpress-website/shared-wordpress-images/db/mysql-release/Dockerfile
      tag_file: tags/release-tag
```

Those images contain `FROM #############.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/shared-mysql` (and shared-wordpress) could this be an issue?

The `tag_file: tags/release-tag`, doesn't seem to be the issue as even without it, this still happens.

This is Concourse 5.0 running on top of Docker in Windows 10.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like something is causing the format of the command to be incorrect? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435418/docker-command-returns-invalid-reference-format

Comment: @DwayneForde not sure how I could retrieve the exact command executed by Concourse, but when I intercept and try to build the image the way I'd usually do, it just works.

Comment: Hmmm maybe it's the extra '.' in the 'build' param?

Comment: @DwayneForde tried with and without :(

Comment: Well, if you feel so inclined, you can look at the logic of the 'out' script for that resource to see if it provides any clues. https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource/blob/master/assets/out

Comment: Beyond that, would need to take a closer look at what the tasks are executing and make sure all the gets/outputs are formatted properly, are in the right place, etc.