# "docker: invalid reference format" when downloading latest version of php

Tags: php, docker

I'm running this command on the Docker PowerShell terminal. I am using VS Code. It gives a "docker: invalid reference format." error message each time.

```
docker run -it --name php_dev --rm -v "${PWD}":/root php:latest bash
```

Comment: It might be because of `"${PWD}":/root`. What happens when you replace `"${PWD}"` with an actual path of your present working directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47435418/596285

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should work on terminal.. check on terminal.

Try this

```
  docker run -it --name php_dev --rm -v "${PWD}:/root" php:latest bash
```