# Why docker container update is not stable?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I use the command `docker container update --cpus 1 target_container` to update the setting. But in most cases it not working and response "you must provide one or more flags when using this command", but somethings it working

Any one know the reason?

Some log is like,

```
$ docker container update --cpus 0.5 target_container
you must provide one or more flags when using this command
$ docker container update --cpus 0.5 target_container
you must provide one or more flags when using this command
$ docker container update --cpus 0.5 target_container
target_container
```

the docker version is

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:19:38 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Aug 15 15:12:41 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: Attach the result of `docker version` command in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) man page includes:

```
--cpus      API 1.29+
```

A `docker version` can show you if your API is equal or above [the API 29](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.29/), which was with  Docker 17.05.

For testing, try `--cpus=1` or `--cpus=0.5`, considering the argument is supposed to be "number of CPUs"

As usual with commands including an hyphen: [don't copy-paste it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309), copy it manually.

Comment: Yes, I use version 1.39. and the strange thing is somethings it works...

Comment: @bran How about the --cpus=x syntax?

Comment: It's also not working, respond with "you must provide one or more flags when using this command"

Comment: @bran you copy-paste the command: would manually typing the '-' in "--cpus' work better?

Comment: you mean to type '-' instead of paste it?

Comment: @bran Yes, because of what I reported in Oct. 2008: https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309

Comment: Wow, it seems this is the problem! really a tricky bug. Thanks.

Comment: @bran Yes, that as bitten me before. That and a space which is actually not a space, but a non-breakable space (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774507/6309)