# R character that looks like whitespace but is not

Tags: r, string, character, special-characters, string-comparison

I seem to have encountered an enigmatic character in R that breaks my code. I am using R, version 4.2.3.

Take the two strings `a` and `b`:

```
a
[1] "Actinomyces naeslundii"
b
[1] "Actinomyces naeslundii"
```

Despite appearances, `a` and `b` are *not* identical.

```
a==b
[1] FALSE
```

Consistently, `a` does not match `b`:

```
grepl(a,b)
[1] FALSE
```

Interestingly, not all characters are identical between `a` and `b`:

```
strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
[1] "A" "c" "t" "i" "n" "o" "m" "y" "c" "e" "s" " " "n" "a" "e" "s" "l" "u" "n" "d" "i" "i"
strsplit(b, "")[[1]]
[1] "A" "c" "t" "i" "n" "o" "m" "y" "c" "e" "s" " " "n" "a" "e" "s" "l" "u" "n" "d" "i" "i"
strsplit(a, "")[[1]] == strsplit(b, "")[[1]]
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[21]  TRUE  TRUE
```

Character #12 is different. It looks like an innocent whitespace, only it isn't:

```
strsplit(a, "")[[1]][12]
[1] " "
strsplit(b, "")[[1]][12]
[1] " "
strsplit(a, "")[[1]][12] == strsplit(b, "")[[1]][12]
[1] FALSE
" " == strsplit(a, "")[[1]][12]
[1] TRUE
" " == strsplit(b, "")[[1]][12]
[1] FALSE
grepl("\\s", strsplit(a, "")[[1]][12])
[1] TRUE
grepl("\\s", strsplit(b, "")[[1]][12])
[1] FALSE
```

Using `dput`:

```
dput(a)
"Actinomyces naeslundii"
dput(b)
"Actinomyces naeslundii"
dput(a, file = "a.dput")
dput(b, file = "b.dput")
```

The generated files differ by *one* byte:

```
$ ls -lah *dput
-rw-r--r-- 1 johannes johannes 25 May 16 20:23 a.dput
-rw-r--r-- 1 johannes johannes 26 May 16 20:23 b.dput
```

Have you encountered this character? What could it be? How can search for it in my data frames?

Comment: Please provide repro data: `dput(a)` and `dplut(b)`

Comment: What's the output of `charToRaw(strsplit(b, "")[[1]][12])`?

Comment: a and b is the same for me.

Comment: Based on your `charToRaw` output, [this seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2774471/903061). I would suggest some regex replacement of general whitespace, `gsub(pattern = "\\s+", replacement = " ", b)` should replace any form of whitespace with a normal space.

Comment: Note that the `\s` token does not match a no break space in either of the regex flavors used by base R.  Use `\h` to match all horizontal whitespace, or match it exactly with `\U00A0`.  `\s` will work with `stringr` and `stringi` functions which use a different regex engine (ICU).

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you; the post indeed is relevant. Using `gsub(pattern = "\\s+", replacement = " ", b)`, however, didn't work.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento thank you; matching pattern `\h` works with package stringr, but not with standard `gsub`. I can make a solution work with the approach suggested by you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the useful comments, I am now in the position to solve above mystery.

There are at least two modifications that render string `b` identical to `a`.

Replacing the unicode character `\U00A0` with space (" "):

```
> b.mod <- gsub("\U00A0", " ", b)
> b.mod == a
[1] TRUE
```

Replacing horizontal whitespace `\h` with space (" ") using packages `stringr` or `stringi`:

```
> b.mod1 <- stringi::stri_replace_all(b, " ", regex = "\\h")
> b.mod1 == a
[1] TRUE
> b.mod2 <- stringr::str_replace_all(b, "\\h", " ")
> b.mod2 == a
[1] TRUE
```

Nevertheless, replacing `\h` or `\s+` with space (" ")  does *not* work with function `gsub` from package `base`:

```
> b.mod3 <- gsub("\\h", " ", b)
> b.mod3 == a
[1] FALSE
> b.mod4 <- gsub("\\s+", " ", b)
> b.mod4 == a
[1] FALSE
```

Again, thanks to all commenters!