# Equivalent of StringBuilder for byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, stringbuilder

This is a simple one, and one that I thought would have been answered. I did try to find an answer on here, but didn't come up with anything - so apologies if there is something I have missed.

Anyway, is there an equivalent of StringBuilder but for byte arrays?

I'm not bothered about all the different overloads of `Append()` - but I'd like to see `Append(byte)` and `Append(byte[])`.

Is there anything around or is it roll-your-own time?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Would [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) work for you? The interface might not be quite as convenient, but it offers a simple way to append bytes, and when you are done you can get the contents as a `byte[]` by calling [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx).

A more `StringBuilder`-like interface could probably be achieved by making an extension method.

**Update**
Extension methods could look like this:

```
public static class MemoryStreamExtensions
{
    public static void Append(this MemoryStream stream, byte value)
    {
        stream.Append(new[] { value });
    }

    public static void Append(this MemoryStream stream, byte[] values)
    {
        stream.Write(values, 0, values.Length);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Append(67);
stream.Append(new byte[] { 68, 69 });
byte[] data = stream.ToArray();  // gets an array with bytes 67, 68 and 69
```

Comment: Yes it would - I like that approach... Thanks

Comment: Can I just ask - I haven't actually seen the syntax `new[] { value }` before - is that inferring the type of the array?

Comment: @Matt: yes, that is correct. In the extension method, `value` is of type `byte`, so `byte[]` is inferred. In the last sample I need to specify `new byte[]` since the compiler would infer the type `int` otherwise.

Comment: @Frederik Mörk - Awesome - thanks. Accepting for the extra 'I've learned something new today' goodness.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Is there any way to munch data from the start of a MemoryStream, so it works like a queue, or is there any other CLR class which can be used as an intra-process pipe?

Comment: @supercat: as far as I know, there is no functionality in `MemoryStream` for that. I don't know any other class than [`Queue<byte>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) from the top of my head.

Comment: To make this even more like a StringBuilder, you could have the extension methods return the stream, itself.

While this may sacrifice a small amount of efficiency, it's not terribly uncommon in builder patterns to return the builder with each method, so that they can be called in one, long statement.

Comment: It'd be more efficient to use `stream.WriteByte(value)` for the `Append` overload that takes a single byte as it would avoid the intermediate `byte[]` array allocation.

Comment: Don't you need to position MemoryStream to the end before appending?

Answer (score 22):

The [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) approach is good, but if you want to have StringBuilder-like behavior add a [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). BinaryWriter provides all the Write overrides you could want.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
writer.Write((byte)67);
writer.Write(new byte[] { 68, 69 });
```

Comment: You can also derive a new class from BinaryWriter if you need special writers.  I made one that handled hton conversions.

Comment: And when done, get the array with `stream.ToArray();`

Comment: Please note, that the `Write(String)` method of the `BinaryWriter` writes a length prefix to the stream!

Answer (score 12):

Probably [`List<byte>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
var byteList = new List<byte>();
byteList.Add(42);
byteList.AddRange(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Comment: ...and then Append(byte) becomes Add(byte) and Append(byte[]) becomes AddRange(byte[]).

Comment: Note that as with `StringBuilder`, adding elements to a `List` is amortized O(1).

Comment: Ok, cool - just one question... Would that be as efficient? I know List<> does some efficient copies for AddRange under the hood, but I didn't know if that works out as the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: @Matt : As with `StringBuilder`, C# `List` uses a backing capacity greater than the size of the data structure in order to enable constant time insertions.  This capacity is doubled as needed.  This strategy is the same strategy `StringBuilder` uses to avoid excessive memory allocations.

Comment: @Brian - Actually, what I was referring to was the way that List<> checks to see if the IEnumerable it is adding in AddRange is an ICollection too, and if it is it adds the elements in a different way... I can't remember exactly how, because I'm not at a machine where I have the reference code downloaded...

Comment: @Matt: Yes, if you pass an `ICollection<T>` then the `AddRange` method uses the collection's `Count` property in order pre-allocate the list to the right size (if necessary). If it's not an `ICollection<T>` then the list will need to be resized on-the-fly as the elements are added.

Comment: How does your answer compare to Fredrik Mörk's 'MemoryStream' answer in terms of versatility, efficiency and closeness to StringBuilder?

Comment: One notable feature of `StringBuilder` that `MemoryStream` is missing is `StringBuilder.Remove()`. `List<byte>` appears to provide an exact equivalent with `List<T>.RemoveRange()`. The inflexibility of `MemoryStream`’s API makes me suspect that it can be more efficient on operations both it and `List<T>` support, but I haven’t tested this.

Answer (score 3):

`List<byte>` Then when you want it as an array you can call `ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public static class MemoryStreams
{
    public static MemoryStream Append(
        this MemoryStream stream
        , byte value
        , out bool done)
    {
        try
        {
            stream.WriteByte(value);
            done = true;
        }
        catch { done = false; }
        return stream;
    }

    public static MemoryStream Append(
        this MemoryStream stream
        , byte[] value
        , out bool done
        , uint offset = 0
        , Nullable<uint> count = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var rLenth = (uint)((value == null) ? 0 : value.Length);

            var rOffset = unchecked((int)(offset & 0x7FFFFFFF));

            var rCount = unchecked((int)((count ?? rLenth) & 0x7FFFFFFF));

            stream.Write(value, rOffset, rCount);
            done = true;
        }
        catch { done = false; }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/674256/bytearraybuilder-a-stringbuilder-for-bytes) project at codeproject.
It's just one class that implements the solution with a MemoryStream as suggested in other answers.