# How to replace the following characters

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I have eml files which I parse them by using streamreader in c#. The issue is that these eml files contain **=C5=9F** and **=C4=B1** respectively **ş** and **ı**

I'm using the following code but I assume its not the right place to set the encoding which the producer of eml file is encoding it before I parse the produced file therefore I assume I need to replace them with the appropriate Unicode chars.  fsEML is an instance of an filestream class which I created it with file.read().

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsEML, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,false);
```

Comment: sounds like you should decode the contents of the file instead, to get plain UTF-8 text back. What you're looking at now doesn't make much sense to interact with.

Comment: It looks like your eml files use some sort of MIME encoding, you should try and decode that.

Comment: encoding of eml file is UTF8 , I just used Server.HtmlDecode and it returns the same string which is =C5=9F

Comment: the encoding isn't UTF-8 or HTML encoding. Look again. :) It seems like you already understood that =C5=9F somehow represents ş, so it sounds like you're almost there.

Comment: thanks, so what method should I use to replace them all, I dont know how many of those is going to be in it. =C5=9F and =C4=B1 are the only one i know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This encoding is called [Quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). There is some functionality in .Net to decode it, but it's not exposed nicely, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226554/c-class-for-decoding-quoted-printable-encoding/2236192#2236192).