# Decode quoted printable correct

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following string:

```
=?utf-8?Q?=5Bproconact_=2D_Verbesserung_=23=32=37=39=5D_=28Neu=29_Stellvertretungen_Benutzerrecht_=2D_andere_k=C3=B6nnen_f=C3=BCr_andere_Stellvertretungen_erstellen_=C3=A4ndern_usw=2E_dadurch_ist_der_Schutz_der_Aktivi=C3=A4ten_Mails_nicht_gew=C3=A4hrt=...
```

which is an encoding of

```
[proconact-Verbesserung #279] (Neu) Stellvertretungen Benutzerrecht - andere können für andere Stellvertretungen erstellen ändern usw. dadurch ist der Schutz der Aktiviäten Mails nicht gewährt.
```

I am searching for a way do decode the quoted string.

I have tried:

```
private static string DecodeQuotedPrintables(string input, string charSet) {
    Encoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
    try {
        enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(charSet);
    } catch {
        enc = new UTF8Encoding();
    }

    var occurences = new Regex(@"(=[0-9A-Z]{2}){1,}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var matches = occurences.Matches(input);

    foreach (Match match in matches) {
        try {
            byte[] b = new byte[match.Groups[0].Value.Length / 3];
            for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups[0].Value.Length / 3; i++) {
                b[i] = byte.Parse(match.Groups[0].Value.Substring(i * 3 + 1, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            }
            char[] hexChar = enc.GetChars(b);
            input = input.Replace(match.Groups[0].Value, hexChar[0].ToString());
        } catch { ;}
    }
    input = input.Replace("?=", "").Replace("=\r\n", "");

    return input;
}
```

when I call (where s is my string)

```
var x = DecodeQuotedPrintables(s, "utf-8");
```

this will return

```
=?utf-8?Q?[proconact_-_Verbesserung_#_(Neu)_Stellvertretungen_Benutzerrecht_-_andere_können_für_andere_Stellvertretungen_erstellen_ändern_usw._dadurch_ist_der_Schutz_der_Aktiviäten_Mails_nicht_gewährt=...
```

What can I do, that there will also the _ and the starting `=?utf-8?Q?` and the trailing `=..` be removed?

Comment: This is evil: `try { ... } catch { ;}`

Comment: what should you end up with? what is the final string that you're trying to take out from the original one?

Comment: This is the original string which I should get:
[proconact-Verbesserung #279] (Neu) Stellvertretungen Benutzerrecht - andere können für andere Stellvertretungen erstellen ändern usw. dadurch ist der Schutz der Aktiviäten Mails nicht gewährt.

Comment: Just a side note: Your source string looks like an a***ed up url-encoded string which could be easily decoded if it had not been mutilated by replacing url-encoded entities like `%23` with `_=23_`. If you cannot control the source string maybe un-replacing the source string and url-decoding it will simplify your method a great deal.

Comment: @Filburt: The source string is a valid (almost) RFC 2047 encoded word; see my answer below.

Comment: @Douglas Didn't know about that one. Good answer with every detail to solve this issue. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text you’re trying to decode is typically found in MIME headers, and is encoded according to the specification defined in the following Internet standard: [RFC 2047: MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) Part Three: Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII Text](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).

There is a sample implementation for such a decoder on GitHub; maybe you can draw some ideas from it: [RFC2047 decoder in C#](https://github.com/petrohi/Stratosphere.Imap/blob/master/Stratosphere/Imap/RFC2047Decoder.cs).

You can also use this online tool for comparing your results: [Online MIME Headers Decoder](http://dogmamix.com/MimeHeadersDecoder/).

Note that your sample text is incorrect. The specification declares:

```
encoded-word = "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
```

Per the specification, any encoded word *must* end in `?=`. Thus, your sample must be corrected from:

```
=?utf-8?Q?=5Bproconact_=2D_Verbesserung_=23=32=37=39=5D_=28Neu=29_Stellvertretungen_Benutzerrecht_=2D_andere_k=C3=B6nnen_f=C3=BCr_andere_Stellvertretungen_erstellen_=C3=A4ndern_usw=2E_dadurch_ist_der_Schutz_der_Aktivi=C3=A4ten_Mails_nicht_gew=C3=A4hrt=
```

…to (scroll to the far right):

```
=?utf-8?Q?=5Bproconact_=2D_Verbesserung_=23=32=37=39=5D_=28Neu=29_Stellvertretungen_Benutzerrecht_=2D_andere_k=C3=B6nnen_f=C3=BCr_andere_Stellvertretungen_erstellen_=C3=A4ndern_usw=2E_dadurch_ist_der_Schutz_der_Aktivi=C3=A4ten_Mails_nicht_gew=C3=A4hrt?=
```

Strictly speaking, your sample is also invalid because it exceeds the 75-character limit imposed on any encoded word; however, most decoders tend to be tolerant of this non-conformity.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested 5+ of code snippets and this is the working one: I've modified the regex part:

**Test line:**

```
    im sistemlerimizde bak=FDm =E7al=FD=FEmas=FD yap=FDlaca=F0=FDndan; www.gib.=
```

**Sample call:**

```
    string encoding = "windows-1254";
    string input = "im sistemlerimizde bak=FDm =E7al=FD=FEmas=FD yap=FDlaca=F0=FDndan; www.gib.=";
    DecodeQuotedPrintables(input, encoding);
```

**Code snippet:**

```
    private static string DecodeQuotedPrintables(string input, string charSet)
    {


        System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7;

        try
        {
            enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(charSet);
        }
        catch
        {
            enc = new UTF8Encoding();
        }



        ////parse looking for =XX where XX is hexadecimal
        //var occurences = new Regex(@"(=[0-9A-Z]{2}){1,}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var occurences = new Regex("(\\=([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]))", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var matches = occurences.Matches(input);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[match.Groups[0].Value.Length / 3];
                for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups[0].Value.Length / 3; i++)
                {
                    b[i] = byte.Parse(match.Groups[0].Value.Substring(i * 3 + 1, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                }
                char[] hexChar = enc.GetChars(b);
                input = input.Replace(match.Groups[0].Value, hexChar[0].ToString());
            }
            catch
            { ;}
        }
        input = input.Replace("?=", "").Replace("=\r\n", "");

        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned at [standard class .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226554/c-class-for-decoding-quoted-printable-encoding) is exist for this purpose.

```
string unicodeString =
            "=?UTF-8?Q?YourText?=";
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = System.Net.Mail.Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString("", unicodeString);
        Console.WriteLine(attachment.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment I'd suggest

```
private static string MessedUpUrlDecode(string input, string encoding)
{
    Encoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();

    try
    {
        enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(charSet);
    }
    catch
    {
        enc = new UTF8Encoding();
    }

    string messedup = input.Split('?')[3];
    string cleaned = input.Replace("_", " ").Replace("=...", ".").Replace("=", "%");

    return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cleaned, enc);
}
```

assuming that the mutilating of the source strings is consistent.

Answer (score -1):

I am not too sure on how to remove the

```
=?utf-8?Q?
```

Unless it appears all the time, if it does, you can do this:

```
input = input.Split('?')[3];
```

To get rid of the trailing '=' you can remove it by:

```
input = input.Remove(input.Length - 1);
```

You can get rid of the '_' by replacing it with a space:

```
input = input.Replace("_", " ");
```

You can use those pieces of code in your DecodeQuotedPrintables function.

Hope this Helps!